# The book is kept "IN/ON" the shelf

Tags: prepositions

Which of them is the proper preposition to use.

Most people say **"*on* the shelf"**, but I have seen **"*in* the shelf"** as well.

Comment: **Where** have you seen "in the shelf"? Context can make a big difference. For example, I might say, "There's a break in the shelf." Or, if I'm talking about the continental shelf, I might say, "There are clams in the shelf." Insofar as books go, it might make sense to say "in the shelf" if we are dealing with a [barrister bookcase](https://www.forcounsel.com/products/0819.jpg).

Answer (score 0):

"On" means that "it is on top of something" (like a tree).  "In" means that "it is inside of something" (like a cupboard). 
 On the shelf also means: Not in active use or consideration; 
For eg: We'll have to put some of those plans on the shelf for a while.

Comment: We need to be careful about making prepositions seem so simple. Sure, "on" might _generally_ mean "on top of something," but not always. Consider these: _His eye is on the sparrow; that store is on Main Street; he has been on the phone for hours; I heard that song on the radio; I got some sleep on the train; the baby fell asleep on her stomach; I've always wanted to live on the beach; that term paper is on my laptop; Bob cut his arm on the pitchfork and has been on pain meds for two days; the drinks are on me_. Some of those could be ambiguous (if not amusing) if _on_ means "on top of".